# factor to numeric NAs introduced by coercion

Tags: r, dataframe

I know that this is a problem that has been addressed hundreds of times already, but I'm having the issue of converting factors to numbers.

Here is some basic code I used to generate a dataframe and convert the factor 'directions' to numeric:

```
size <- c(1,2,3,2)
directions <- factor(c("North", "East", "South", "South"))

df <- data.frame(size,directions)

fac_indx <- sapply(df, is.factor)
df[fac_indx] <- lapply(df[fac_indx], function(x) as.numeric(as.character(x)))
```

I'm still getting NAs and I don't understand what I've done wrong. I wanted to make sure I understand what is happening when converting a factor to a number, but this has only created another issue for me.

If anyone could tell me what I've done wrong, or what I'm missing here I would greatly appreciate it.

Best,
Curtis

Comment: You are basically trying to do `as.numeric("North")`, which isn't a very logical conversion. Maybe get rid of `as.character`? Furthermore, it would help if you specify what the desired output should be.

Comment: @Jaap, what I was hoping to get was to convert the factor column to a numeric column with the unique numeric IDs associated with each level of the factor

Comment: so df$directions would now be equal to c(2,1,3,3)

Comment: @Jaap removing the as.character did work for what I wanted, but I don't understand why it worked necessarily. From reading the documentation for `factor` stated that when converting between the factor to numeric would require using `as.numeric(as.character(f))`

Comment: Factors are stored as integers with labels. Converting to numeric as described in the helpfile is meant for situations like this: `x <- factor(c("2","3","5"))` where the levels/labels contain numeric information.

Comment: It seems to me that you're not really trying to *convert the factor to a numeric value*, but rather, you're trying to retrieve the factor level and replace the factor with that numeric value, so you don't want *convert the factor to a character*, you simply want to *access the factor levels* -- which Emil Bode's answer will achieve.

Answer (score 3):

You basically have the opposite problem then what the docs warn for!

In this case, `as.numeric(x)` should work fine.

What is far more often the problem, is someone asking the question "Hey, why does this code not work?"

```
df <- data.frame(nums=c(6,4,8,2,5,'unknown'))
as.numeric(df$nums)
# or
myfactor <- factor(11:20)
as.numeric(myfactor[3])
```

In that case, we have to explain that a factor is just a list of possible values, and as.numeric returns just the underlying representation. It's not that `as.numeric` is *wrong*, it's just that with a factor, it does something most people don't expect.
And in that case `as.numeric(as.character(myfactor[3]))` returns 13, as would be expected from `(11:20)[3]`

The only thing you **do** have to be careful about is what your levels actually are. By default, they are sorted alphabetically, which may not be what you want. It's easiest to solve by giving a levels argument when assigning your values:

```
directions <- factor(c("North", "East", "South", "South"), levels=
   c('North', 'East', 'South', 'West'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want to convert your directions into numerical values, right? If that's what you want, you can define another variable containing numerical values for each direction, thus:

```
df$directions.num <- ifelse(df$directions=="North", 1,
                            ifelse(df$directions=="East", 2,
                                   ifelse(df$directions=="South", 3, 4)))
df
  size directions directions.num
1    1      North              1
2    2       East              2
3    3      South              3
4    2      South              3
```

Answer (score 0):

A table lookup with `switch` is also a possibility.

```
sapply(df$directions, function(d)
  switch(as.character(d),
         "East" = 1,
         "North" = 2,
         "South" = 3,
         "West" = 4
  )
)
#[1] 2 1 3 3
```

Then assign the result of the above instruction to a new column of the data.frame.